# Using OpenCover or other tool to generate test report incremently

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

We are using OpenCover in C# project. Is there any way to append the result of new runs of the tests to the old `results.xml` generated by OpenCover? Or is there any other tool with this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

[AxoCover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover), which uses OpenCover and can be installed in Visual Studio through `Tools - Extensions and Updates...`, for every run creates a directory containing the file `coverageReport.xml` which uses the same format as OpenCover.

These reports could then be merged using XSLT.  See the results here for how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+merge+two+xml+files